# testing a simple onClick in react-testing-library not working. times called always 0

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have the following, very simple, component:

```
  const { openDrawer, setOpenDrawer } = useContext(DrawerContext)

    const toggleDrawer = (open: boolean) => {
        setOpenDrawer(open)
    }

    return (
        <Button data-testid="ClickIndicator" onClick={() => toggleDrawer(true)} />
    )
```

I'm trying to test it by simply checking if the method is being called. The button is a styled component which returns a div now I'm trying to test this component with the following test:

```
    it('should open drawer when ClickIndicator is clicked', () => {
        const mockOnClick = jest.fn()
        const { getByTestId } = render(<Button />)
      
        const clickIndicator = getByTestId('ClickIndicator')

        fireEvent.click(clickIndicator)

        expect(mockOnClick).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)

    })
```

But it just doesn't return it as being called. The received number of calls stays 0 and I have no clue why. Is there anyone we could help me out? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: i don't have any experience with jest but based on https://codewithhugo.com/jest-fn-spyon-stub-mock/ perhaps you can replace jest.fn() with jest.spyOn(toggleDrawer, 'setOpenDrawer'); since the problem is that you are not passing the mockOnClick to your Button Component

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks to help from laserany and zjb I could fix it by doing the following! thank you very much!

I was stupidly not passing the mock function to the button as I should.

```
  it('should open drawer when ClickIndicator is clicked', () => {
        const mockOnClick = jest.fn()
        const { getByTestId } = render(<Button onClick={mockOnClick()} />)
      
        const clickIndicator = getByTestId('ClickIndicator')

        fireEvent.click(clickIndicator)

        expect(mockOnClick).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)

    })
```

Comment: It's possible only because you don't have a component here. You won't be able to mock toggleDrawer defined inside a component, this is the limitation of functional components.

Comment: this is wrong it will wark because you call mockOnClick() when you pass iit. Remove fireEvent.click() and the test will still pass

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that what you give to onClick needs to be a function.

`toggleDrawer(true)` is an expression, so only evaluated once on render.

Try `() => toggleDrawer(true)`. This way each time you click, the function will be executed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! but still no luck () => toggleDrawer(true) doesn't work either. I've updated my question. Thank you!